# Prove that every planar graph is $6$-choosable without using Thomassens's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every planar graph is $6$-choosable without using Thomassens's theorem

> > **Thomassens's theorem**: every planar graph is $5$-choosable

Now I'm kinda confused because if a graph is $5$-choosable then, it's $6$ choosable automatically, so is this a typo in the book and the question should be every planar graph is $5$-choosable?

Assuming this is not a typo, then I need to show that $\chi_l(G) = 6$ for every planar graph $G$.

I know that $G$ is a planar graph, so $G$ is $4$-colorable, so $\chi_l (G) \geq 4$. I also know that $m \leq 3n-6$ for $n\geq 3$ and $G$ must contain a vertex of degree $5$ or less.

I have the feeling that the info about $G$ must contain a vertex of degree $5$ or less will help me prove this but I can't get anything out of this except $\delta(G) \leq 5$, I wonder if anyone would tell me how is this related to $\chi_l(G)=6$?

Comment: In theory it should be "easier" to prove 6-choosability than 5-choosability, so it's likely not a typo. They want you to prove a weaker statement from scratch without using the stronger theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very likely not a typo, as proving every planar graph is 5-choosable amounts to reproducing Thomassen's theorem, which may be too difficult for an exercise, whereas proving every planar graph is 6-choosable is rather simple.

You need to show that $\chi_l(G) \le 6$ for every planar graph $G$; as Thomassen's theorem shows, $\chi_l(G) = 6$ is false for every planar graph.

You can indeed use the fact that $G$ must contain a vertex of degree 5 or less to solve the problem.  We prove the theorem by induction, i.e. we use induction the following statement:

Claim. A graph with $n$ vertices is 6-choosable.

Base case $n = 0$: A graph with no vertices is vacuously 6-choosable.

Inductive step: Assume the claim is true for all graphs with $n-1$ vertices.  We will prove the claim for a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices. We choose a list assignment $L$ such that $|L(v)| \ge 6$ for all $v \in G$. We know that $G$ has a vertex of degree 5 or less; let $u$ be such a vertex. $G - u$ has $n-1$ vertices, so by the induction hypothesis $G - u$ is 6-choosable. Hence, we can color $G - u$ from $L$.  Since $u$ is adjacent to at most 5 other vertices, and $|L(u)| \ge 6$, we can choose a color from $L(u)$ that is different from any adjacent color.  So $G$ can be colored, and the theorem is proved.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your answer, how do you know $\chi_l(G) \leq 6$ for every planar graph $G$, a planar graph mean $\delta(G) \leq 5$ but that doesn't say that $\Delta(G) =5$ so I can't use the fact $\chi_l(G) \leq 1+ \Delta(G)$ right? 

I don't understand you answer in induction part either, can you explain it a little bit further please?

Comment: We don't know that $\Delta(G)=5$, so I am not using that.  I will try to expand on the induction.

Comment: Edited; does that help?

Comment: yes, the induction part, I understand it very well now. In the induction part you want to show $\chi_l(G) \geq 6$, am I correct? So on the part $\chi_l(G) \leq 6$, you say by Thomassene's theorem, but I'm not allowed to use that, so I can't make that arguement , am I? I'm struggle on this problem because I know the graph can be color using color list with smaller size, so I can't argue that if we use color list of size $5% we can't color the graph.

Comment: No, the induction shows that $\chi_l (G) \le 6$.  We cannot prove that $\chi_l (G) \ge 6$, because it isn't true.  $\chi_l(G)$ for planar graphs can range anywhere from 0 (the empty graph) up to 5 (the maximum possible due to Thomassen's theorem).  So we can't hope for a lower bound other than 0, unless we reduce the set of graphs we are talking about.